# Uncaught Error: Class 'Service\UsersService' not found

Tags: php, mysql, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to run my php-based application, which connects to a mysql DB, launched through docker-compose.

i get this message when i connect to localhost:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Service\UsersService' not found in /var/www/html/dic/users.php:3 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/web/index.php(3): require() #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/dic/users.php on line 3

user.php

```
<?php

return new Service\UsersService(
    require "../config/db-connection.php"
);
```

UsersService.php

```
<?php

namespace Service;

use Entity\User;
use PDO;

class UsersService
{
    protected $db;

    public function __construct(PDO $db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function getLastJoined(): array
    {
        return $this->db->query(
            "SELECT id, joined, name FROM user ORDER BY joined DESC LIMIT 10"
        )->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, User::class);
    }

    public function getById(string $id): ?User
    {
        $user = $this->db->query("SELECT id, joined, name FROM user WHERE id = " . $this->db->quote($id))->fetchObject(User::class);

        return ($user === false) ? null: $user;
    }
}
```

index.php

```
<?php

$lastJoinedUsers = (require "../dic/users.php")->getLastJoined();

switch (require "../dic/negotiated_format.php") {
    case "text/html":
        (new Views\Layout(
            "Twitter - Newcomers", new Views\Users\Listing($lastJoinedUsers), true
        ))();
        exit;

    case "application/json":
        header("Content-Type: application/json");
        echo json_encode($lastJoinedUsers);
        exit;
}

http_response_code(406);
```

I appreciate any help!!

Comment: Looks like you need to import `UserService` in your `user.php` file. E.g:  `require_once 'path/to/UserService.php';`

Comment: add this: <?php

return new Service\UsersService(
    require "../config/db-connection.php"
    require_once "../Service/UserService.php";
);        I have this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'require_once' (T_REQUIRE_ONCE), expecting ',' or ')' in /var/www/html/dic/users.php on line 5